# contained and contained in, and some other translation issues

Tags: translation

Below, you can see page 85 of [ST_Lite_JxE081_v00.02](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/epfiles/ST_Lite_JxE081_v00.02.pdf) .It is a Security-Target (a document that indicate some security specification of an IT production) for *JCOP Smart cards.*

[image]

**TSF = Target Security Functions**

I can't understand the sections that I marked.

In the second line of first marked item: "the application package contained in the information to which the evidence applies", which one is true?

1. the application package is in the information (I mean the information containing the application package) or the information is in the application package (I mean the application package containing the information.)?
2. what is the meaning of "to which the evidence applies"? the evidence applies what? information or application package?

And also in the second marked item, I can't understand it!

1. "to recipient given at the time when the ..." means that : the evidence are verify for recipient? the evidence are from recipient? please explain it for me.

Comment: I started to answer, but then, upon closer reading of the document, I see that it is unclear in exactly those places where clarity is required.

Comment: Ugg.  That security specification is terribly written.  If you are asking because you are actually designing to this spec, you should probably direct questions back to the author.  It would be a shame if we misinterpreted the spec and you got dinged for it.  If you are asking in order to improve your English...it's going to be difficult with that as raw material.

Comment: @TRomano Oops! I thought I can't understand the document because my English knowledge is weak! I didn't know the problem is the document not me! :D

Comment: @Adam Thank you, I didn't asked just for improving my English knowledge! I must translate it unfortunately. But improving my knowledge is one of the goals also :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I understand it.  I could be completely wrong.  Please take everything @Adam commented above to heart.

---

1. The statement here in FC0_NRO.2.1/CM:

> The TSF shall enforce the generation of evidence origin for transmitted application packages ...

seems to imply some sort of process (signing? certifying?) will create some new information given a transmitted application package, maybe something like a manifest file or similar.

So, in the following sentence in FCO_NRO.2.2/CM:

"Information" here I think means "transmitted application packages" per FCO_NRO.2.1/CM.  I'm guessing it's assumed that whatever process above is expected to be used for something other than application packages, hence the generic term "information."

"Application package contained in the information" I think means "name of the application package".

---

2. "To which the evidence applies" I think would be the same application package, again a generic term used for the same reason "information" was used above.

---

1. "Recipient" is the receiver of the transmitted application packages (whoever/whatever downloads it?)

Comment: Thank you dear friend.
**"Application package contained in the information" I think means "name of the application package".** Do you mean,it means "The name of application package that there is in the information"?

Comment: **"Recipient" is the receiver of the transmitted application packages**. The recipient is one of the parts of the card or is the person who works with the card?

Comment: Yes on the first question, and I'd say "recipient" refers to the person who works with the card (mostly because it says the evidence is not kept on the card).